# Performant HMAC Calculation with OpenSSL

Tags: c, performance, openssl, hmac

I am doing some performance analysis of our code when we use OpenSSL (3.0) for our crypto abstraction layer. I noticed doing HMAC calculations are taking the bulk of our time, and I wondered if there is a more efficient way to go about doing things. We have two main function ([QuicHashCreate](https://github.com/microsoft/msquic/blob/main/src/platform/tls_openssl.c#L1926) and [QuicHashCompute](https://github.com/microsoft/msquic/blob/main/src/platform/tls_openssl.c#L1996)) that we essentially take { Algorithm, Salt/Secret, Input } and generate the HMAC output.

The functions we call effectively come down to:

- `EVP_MD_CTX_new`
- `EVP_PKEY_new_mac_key`
- `EVP_DigestSignInit`
- `EVP_DigestSignUpdate`
- `EVP_DigestSignFinal`
- `EVP_PKEY_free`
- `EVP_MD_CTX_free`

From my analysis, `EVP_PKEY_new_mac_key` and `EVP_DigestSignInit` end up consuming nearly all my CPU. As the Salt/Secrets used are dynamic I can't really cache these objects. Is there a better, more performant way to go about this?

Comment: FYI, I'm trying out using HMAC_CTX directly, but supposedly it's deprecated in 3.0...

Comment: Both the salt and keygen require a non-trivial amount of rng. Are you sure you're not entropy starved? An actual [mcve] that produces your problem, along with some information on the platform and toolkit that built the OpenSSL kit you're using, may be helpful as well, and should be included in your post.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just posted an "answer" that works and fixes the problem but requires me to ignore the deprecated warnings. I assume if those work just fine, then I am not "entropy starved" though I don't know what you mean exactly.

Comment: So... no on the [mcve]. Well, at least you have something that works. You could always look at the source of EVP_PKEY_new_mac_key etc to see what they're doing differently. Regardless, you still can't assume lack of entropy starvation if the HMAC methods are lighter on the rng load than the EVP family. Chance are source will be the ultimate tell-all (usually is).

Comment: Have you tried the new EVP_MAC APIs in OpenSSL 3.0: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_MAC_init.html

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this because it works, but not accepting it because it's marked as deprecated with the latest OpenSSL version.

The following replacement calls work:

- `HMAC_CTX_new`
- `HMAC_Init_ex`
- `HMAC_Update`
- `HMAC_Final`

And now, HMAC doesn't even show up in my performance traces. This completely fixed my problems, but I'd like to know if there is yet a better way to do this.